# Como colocar uma div com conteudo da pagina do lado do menu vertical que veio incluido?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte estrutura, por enquanto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O menu lateral veio por `include_once 'menu.php'` e a pagina que estamos vendo é a `home.php`.

CSS do menu:

```
.longBarVertical {
    width: 180px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

.logoMenu {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.logoMenu img {
    width: 50px;
}

.menuVertical {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.menuVertical li a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.menuVertical li:hover a, .menuVertical li:hover a i {
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
```

Até ai talvez esteja tudo certo, o que eu gostaria era de conseguir colocar a `div` em vermelho que está escrito "Home" ao lado do menu lateral e poder colocar `widht: 100%`. Do jeito que está no print, está com `width: 200px` (apenas para exemplo) e se eu colocar `width: 100%`, a `div` fica embaixo do menu lateral, o que não é o desejado.

Códigos da `div` em vermelho, também pode ser chamada de "conteudo":

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; float: left;">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Talvez não seja possivel colocar `width: 100%` pra div "conteudo", caso não seja, como eu posso fazer pra div "conteudo" ficar ao lado direito do menu e ocupar o restante da tela? (O restante seria da borda do menu até o lado direito da pagina, algo como um (hipoteticamente) `width: 100%-180px`.

Desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Estou usando o framework `Bootstrap 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue colocando as `divs` dentro da `div` com `class="row no-gutters"`:

```css
ul, li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

.longBarVertical {
    width: 180px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

.logoMenu {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.logoMenu img {
    width: 50px;
}

.menuVertical {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.menuVertical li a {
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.menuVertical li:hover a, .menuVertical li:hover a i {
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
    transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row no-gutters">
   <div class="menuVertical longBarVertical">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col" style="background: red;">
       <h1>Home</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show de bola ÐvÐ, functionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!